# Round to nearest 7.5 with limited mathematical functions

Tags: linear-algebra, rounding-unit

I am working with a piece of software with limited mathematical functions and I need to round a double value to the nearest multiple of 7.5.

Values will be in the range 0 to 360 (of type double).

I believe I can use the formula:

$$Round(x/7.5)*7.5$$

but the software doesn't have a round function (that I can find at least!)

The functions I have available are:

- Standard add, subtract, multiply and divide.
- Brackets are permitted
- ABS(x) - returns absolute value of x
- COS SIN TAN and their inverse
- EXP(x) - returns e to power x
- INT(x) - returns x rounded down to nearest integer (i.e truncates x)
- LN(x) - returns the natural base logarithm of x
- LOG(x) - returns the base 10 logarithm of x
- MOD(x,y) - returns the remainder of x divided by y
- SQRT(x) - returns the square root of x

They all accept integers or doubles and return appropriate values types.

So is it possible to round to the nearest 7.5 with only these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathrm{round}(x) = \mathrm{int}(0.5+\mathrm{abs}(x)) \frac{x}{\mathrm{abs}(x)}$ when $x\neq 0$. Since your $x$ is nonnegative, the formula simplifies to $\mathrm{round}(x) = \mathrm{int}(0.5+x)$ and also holds for $x=0$. So, $7.5 \; \mathrm{round}(\frac{x}{7.5}) = 7.5 \; \mathrm{int}(0.5 + \frac{x}{7.5})$

Comment: Brilliant! Works great, thank you. I'm now curious if it could be done without the int function too :)

Comment: You can use $x-\textrm{mod}(x,1)$ for rounding down instead of $\textrm{int}$.